# How to restrict a website to get access to a specific path through IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm looking for a way to restrict a website served by IIS so that the website can get access to the specific folder or drive not more, let me illustrate it.

Imagine I have two websites `A` and `B` served by IIS, you can put following code in code-behind of both websites:

```
string windowsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows)
string path = windowsPath + @"\Microsoft.NET\Framework";
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
```

I need a way through IIS to restrict website `A` not be able to get access to the mentioned `directories` and only website `B` be able to do that. In other words I want to restrict read access.

I suppose it should have a simple solution because it's what hosting servers deal with. It's obvious that you can't put a piece of code in your website in a web hosting server and simply get access to list files name located in drive C of the hosting server.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. See in IIS, public pages are public-anyone can access them. If it's a public page, you allow anonymous access otherwise your application can restrict access to specific pages or you can use IIS to restrict access to those pages through windows or IIS. You're asking a very general and broad question and there is ample info on the subject online.

Comment: No, it's not about the page, it's about restricting a website developer, I need to restrict access in code-behind of a page, I searched about it but I couldn't find what I need.

Comment: Search for [code access security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/code-access-security).

Comment: I don't think you can achieve such precise permissions for separate web apps with configuring IIS. As @CodingYoshi said CAS may help you... but I don't believe you can configure it at IIS level. More search terms: "sandboxing", "partial trust".

Comment: If you keep the default permissions unchanged, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/981949/description-of-default-permissions-and-user-rights-for-iis-7-0-and-lat , then by denying the application pool identity of site A to access certain folders, you should achieve part of your goals. However, .NET Framework installation folder must be accessible, or an ASP.NET app cannot even be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching a lot I found the solution, I thought it might be useful for ones who will stumble upon this matter later, so I documented the solution.

**Note:**
From IIS 7.5 on, you have more access on user who is running a website.
Every application pool you make, creates an internal user which is hidden and is known as `AppPoolIdentity`.

**The goal:**
Imagine We have two websites `A` and `B`, we also have a folder named `SecurityTest` located in `D:\Temp`, there are 6 folders inside it under the names 1 to 6, we consider to allow website A get the name of the folders inside `SecurityTest` while we tend to prevent website `B` to do that.

**Step 1:**
Firstly, create a website through VisualStudio, I put a server side button in the form, I consider to get name of folders in the specified path (say `D:\Temp\SecurityTest`), So here's the code I place in code behind to be triggered when the button is clicked:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Label1.Text = string.Empty;
    string path = @"D:\Temp\SecurityTest";
    var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

    for (int i = 0; i < directories.Length; i++)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(directories[i]);
        Label1.Text += fileName + "<br />";
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Now let's deal with IIS. Add two websites (or applications) to the IIS, name them `A` and `B`, the physical path for both are the same, only change port number, for instance set 81 as port number for website A and 82 for website B. Note that new application pool is created by default with the same name of your website (if you create a new application instead of new website, you should create a new application pool by yourself).

[image]

**Step 3:** Now in the `Connections` pane, click on website `A`, from middle pane, double click on `Authentication` located in the `IIS` category. Then click on `Anonymous Authentication`, after that from 'Actions' pane at the right side, click on `Edit`.

Now select `Application pool identity` and click on `OK`. By following these steps you chose `AplicationPoolIdentity` user as the user who handles website `A`. Follow these steps for website `B`.

[image]

**Step 4:** Go to the path`D:\Temp`, right click on the folder named `SecurityTest`, on the `Security` tab, on the `Group or user names` category, you can see users listed who have access to the folder, these users are granted permission at the creation time by default. You might see more or less though but the point is that you should add website `A` ApplicationPoolIdentity user and remove all other users, so remove `Users` which gives access to **all** users, after that remove `Authenticated users` from the list too.

[image]

Keep in mind that you can't simply remove these users, you should `Disable Inheritance` first. here's the steps to achieve that:

Since you tend to allow website `A` to get directories, you need to add the user corresponding to the website `A`, now you need to follow the next step.

**Step 4-1:** On the same dialogue, click on `Add` to add new user, from here you can't find the user related to the website `A` since it's a hidden and internal (and virtual) user, I mean the `AppPoolIdentity` user for website `A`. You should type the name on the following pattern:

`IIS APPPOOL\<app_pool_name>`

So for website `A` I should type `IIS APPPOOL\A`, click on `Check Names` to make sure whether the user exists or not, finally press OK button.

[image]

**Step 4-2:** To prevent other users to get access to the webite `A`, click on `Advanced` button, click on `Disable inheritance`, when you encounter the warning message, select the first option (Convert) preferably, then press OK to close the dialogue.

Now in `Security` tab, click on `Edit` button to change permissions. Here you can remove users you don't need, like `Authenticated Users` and `Users`. From now on both websites `A` and `B` won't be able to get folders name.

Now get back to IIS panel and click on website `A` in the left Pane, then click on `Browse *:81 (http)` link, you can see the website A on your browser, do the same for website `B` to open it in the browser. When you click on button in website `A` you can observe a list of folders from 1 t 6 while you get following error when you click on the button to get directories on the website `B`.

`Access to the path 'D:\Temp\SecurityTest' is denied.`

That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand how pipeline work, you would know that we can only filter permission based by injecting module. So there are few things we can do with IIS configuration.

Asp.net application activated under IIS worker process with Application pool identity. Since Site A and Site B used different managed service account. You could remove IIS apppool\A's permission to prevent site A from reading folder.

Since read permission for application pool identity to access windows\microsoft.net is necessary when activating worker process. It is not recommended to restrict the permission

[image]